# Node.js Http POST hangs forever on mysql queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, post, coffeescript

Here what im trying to do is check if there is a username and email matching in db, and if there is not, register a new user. Using coffescript.

When i try to make a POST to the route, morgan prints

> POST /register - - ms - -

And postman hangs forever...

There are no console errors, and no POSTMAN responses...

Anyone have any idea of what is causing the issue?

```
app.post '/register', (req, res, next) ->
  email = req.body.email
  username = req.body.username
  emailORUsernameExists = checkEmailUsername email, username

  unless emailORUsernameExists
    password = req.body.password
    query = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (" + email + "," + username + "," + password + ")"
    bcrypt.genSalt 10, (err, salt) ->
      bcrypt.hash password, salt, (err, hash) ->
        # Store hashed password in DB.
        connection.query query, (err, result) ->
          if err
            throw err
          console.log "1 record inserted!"

checkEmailUsername = (mail, user) ->
  query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?"
  connection.query query, [mail, user], (err, row, fields) ->
    if err
      console.log err

    if row.length > 0
      # return true if there is a matching username and password
      return true
    else
      # if there is not, return false
      return false
```

Also, JS version

```
  app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var email, emailORUsernameExists, password, query, username;
    email = req.body.email;
    username = req.body.username;
    emailORUsernameExists = checkEmailUsername(email, username);
    if (!emailORUsernameExists) {
      password = req.body.password;
      query = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (" + email + "," + username + "," + password + ")";
      return bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
          return connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            return console.log("1 record inserted!");
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });

  checkEmailUsername = function(mail, user) {
    var query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";
    return connection.query(query, [mail, user], function(err, row, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      if (row.length > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`res` is never called anywhere in the code which results in the request hanging.

A more modern approach to your code would look something like the following:

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, username } = req.body

  // Since our function now returns a Promise we can use await.
  // Avoids that triangle of doom/callback hell.
  const emailORUsernameExists = await checkEmailUsername(email, username)

  if (!emailORUsernameExists) {
    let { password } = req.body

    // Hash the password BEFORE saving to the database
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

    const query = `INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (${email}, ${username}, ${password}`

    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // Something went wrong, let the client know this.
        res.status(500).json({ error: err })
        return
      }
      // All went well.
      res.status(201).json()
    })
  }
})

function checkEmailUsername (mail, user) {
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?'

  // I don't think node-mysql supports Promises.
  // Promise is used to make the code read more synchronous
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, [mail, user], (err, row, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      if (row.length > 0) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        resolve(false)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The code above is untested, so you will need to adjust it to fit your needs.